# Why is RabbitMQ reader flushing my queue?

Tags: rabbitmq

I have some simple code to put a few things on a queue:

```
val factory = new ConnectionFactory()
factory.setHost("localhost")
val connection = factory.newConnection()
val channel = connection.createChannel()
channel.basicPublish("", "myq", null, "AAA".getBytes()) 
channel.basicPublish("", "myq", null, "BBB".getBytes()) 
channel.basicPublish("", "myq", null, "CCC".getBytes()) 
channel.close()
connection.close()
```

This seems to work.  After running this I can do 'rabbitmqctl list_queues' and see myq with 3 items in it.

Now (in a different process) I run reader code to grab **just 1** element from the queue:

```
val factory = new ConnectionFactory()
factory.setHost("localhost")
val connection = factory.newConnection()
val channel = connection.createChannel()
channel.queueDeclare("myq", false, false, false, null)
val consumer = new QueueingConsumer(channel)
channel.basicConsume("myq", true, consumer)

// Grab just one message from queue
val delivery = consumer.nextDelivery()
val message = new String(delivery.getBody())

println(" [x] Received '" + message + "'")
channel.close()
connection.close()
```

This successfully retrieves the first item on the queue (AAA). But... now when I run 'rabbitmqctl list_queues' I see 0 items in my queue, and of course re-running my reader hangs/waits because the queue is now empty.  Why did the other items in the queue disappear?

Comment: Why you use empty exchange?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to not be using basicQos. With basicQos set to one, then you can achieve what you want, otherwise RabbitMQ will considered the prefetch setting to be unlimited, and send all the messages (or as many as it can) to the process that first did a basicConsume().

More info here: http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-java.html bellow "Fair Dispatch"